# .NET MAUI - Error with shell navigation with dictionary as parameter

Tags: c#, .net, shell, maui

I want to navigate to a Page with multiple parameters.

For that, I use a Dictionary:

```
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(DetailPage)}?",
    new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        ["Name"] = s.RecipeName,
        ["Ingredients"] = s.Ingredients,
        ["Steps"] = s.Steps
    });
```

But in Visual Studio, I get this error:

> Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>' to 'bool'

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: The 2nd parameter is a bool that controls animation

Comment: The problem here is probably that you have a `Dictionary<string, string>` while the `GoToAsync()` override that you're using expects a `IDictionary<string, object>`. Try changing the second `string` type parameter to `object`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.shell.gotoasync?view=net-maui-7.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method signature of `GoToAsync()` expects a `bool` or a `IDictionary<string, object>` as the second argument, while you're passing it a `Dictionary<string, string>`.

Since the compiler cannot find any matching overloads, it just tries with first one. However, your `Dictionary<string, string>` cannot be typecast to `bool`, hence the compiler error.

More info on the different `GoToAsync()` variants: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.shell.gotoasync?view=net-maui-7.0

Note that `Dictionary<string, string>` is not the same as `Dictionary<string, object>`, only the latter is acceptable for the compiler since it has the same type arguments specified as the interface in the signature of the second variant of the method overloads (or the first one, if you provide a `bool` in second place).

In order to fix this, change your code to the following:

```cs
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"nameof(DetailPage)}?",
    new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        ["Name"] = s.RecipeName,
        ["Ingredients"] = s.Ingredients,
        ["Steps"] = s.Steps
    }
);
```

This should work, because you can assign a `string` to `object`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be

```
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(DetailPage), true, new Dictionary<string, object> {
    {"Name", s.RecipeName },
    {"Ingredients", s.Ingredients},
    {"Steps", s.Steps}
});
```